# Exporting a 16-bit image from QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, export, qgis-2

Could someone explain how to export a 16-bit image from QGIS ?

I have imported data and coloured it as I want, but need to export it as a 16-bit image, as 8-bit is giving a terracing effect. I believe, I need to use this code in *OSGeo4W Shell*, but I don't know how to use it.

```
gdal_translate -ot Int16 -srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize -outsize xsize ysize src_dataset dst_dataset
```

Here is a screenshot of my map, which has the following extent:

Xmin 510000, Ymin 156000, Xmax 528000, Ymax 174000

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Robert! For a simple translation to 16-bit, you could just type `gdal_translate -ot Int16 path/to/input.tif pth/to/output.tif` in the OSGeo4W shell.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your help. I have tried this but get an error. "ERROR 4: `LIDAR_DTM_2m.qqs' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name." If I link it back to the original data it works but the image is just a black square.

Comment: Maybe:  click on the layer/ choose "Save as"/ check "Rendered" ?

Comment: Dave, I have tried this but it only saves as 8-bit image. Also, I have 298 layers (small squares) which make up my map, so need to combine them together. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Rather late, but with a script that uses `gdal` (in Python, for example) this should be possible by using `band.SetColorTable()`. This assumes that the colortable exists in a form where every greyvalue has a set of 4 values (R, G, B, Alpha). Would either require some clever scripting or a very long textfile.

Comment: You can use the Raster > Conversion > Translate menu in QGIS 3+ Edit the bottom box by hand and run.  Gdal tools are very powerful, it's well worth learning to use them from the command line.  This is very easy on linux, but a bit convoluted on Windows as you need to make sure your environment has been set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 3+ one can issue the command directly from the interface:
`Raster` -> `Conversion` -> `Translate (Convert Format)`

[image]

and select `Int16` in `Output Data Type`:

[image]

The output file is a 16 bit one:

[image]